# convert const async function into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, magenta

I have a React class that where i'm taking a vanilla js program, and trying to implement it as a React class. The end state should be a music generator.

Right now, im getting audio which is great, but it is just a static sequence. The cool part is in the const async function. Being new to front end in general, im not sure how to convert the const async function into a usable part of a react component, so that it doesnt just play the note sequence, but actually runs the rnn.

This is the class:

```
class Beat3 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.improvCheckpoint = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/magentadata/js/checkpoints/music_rnn/chord_pitches_improv'
    this.improvRNN = new mm.MusicRNN(this.improvCheckpoint)
    this.synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster()
    const { midi, Note } = Tonal
    this.player = new mm.Player();

    this.sequence = {
      BEATB: {
      ticksPerQuarter: 360,
      totalTime: 2,
      timeSignatures: [{ time: 0, numerator: 4, denominator: 4 }],
      tempos: [{ time: 0, qpm: 300 }],
      notes: [
        { pitch: 60.3, startTime: 0, endTime: 0.9 },
        { pitch: 65.4, startTime: 0.9, endTime: 1.9 },
        { pitch: 67.2, startTime: 1.9, endTime: 2.7 },
      ]
    }
  }

    this.quantizedSequence = mm.sequences.quantizeNoteSequence(this.sequence, 1)

    /*This is what Im trying to have run in the react class*/

    const startProgram = async () => {
    try {
    await this.improvRNN.initialize()
    let improvisedMelody = await this.improvRNN.continueSequence(
      this.quantizedSequence, 60, 1.1, [60, 75,67,69])

    const playOriginalMelody = () => {
      this.sequence.notes.forEach(note => {
        this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(Note.fromMidi(note.pitch),
        note.endTime - note.startTime, note.startTime)
      })
    }

    const playGeneratedMelody = () => {
      improvisedMelody.notes.forEach(note => {
        this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(Note.fromMidi(note.pitch),
        note.quantizedEndStep - note.quantizedStartStep, note.quantizedStartStep)
      })
    }

    const originalMelodyButton = document.getElementById('b1a')
    const generatedMelodyButton = document.getElementById('b1b')
    originalMelodyButton.onclick = () => {
      playOriginalMelody()
    }
    generatedMelodyButton.onclick = () => {
      playGeneratedMelody()
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
 }
}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.player.start(this.sequence.BEATB);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.player.stop();
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div class="b1a">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Beat3
```

When i add the async to the componentDidMount, the sound still comes up, but the const buttons inside do not show up. I'm sure its an easy fix, and an explanation of what to do here would be very helpful.

componentDidMount with async:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.player.start(this.sequence.BEATB);
    const startProgram = async () => {
    try {
    await this.improvRNN.initialize()
    let improvisedMelody = await this.improvRNN.continueSequence(
      this.quantizedSequence, 60, 1.1, [60, 75,67,69])
    const playOriginalMelody = () => {
      this.sequence.notes.forEach(note => {
        this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(Note.fromMidi(note.pitch),
        note.endTime - note.startTime, note.startTime)
      })
    }
    const playGeneratedMelody = () => {
      improvisedMelody.notes.forEach(note => {
        this.synth.triggerAttackRelease(Note.fromMidi(note.pitch),
        note.quantizedEndStep - note.quantizedStartStep, note.quantizedStartStep)
      })
    }
    const originalMelodyButton = document.getElementById('b1a')
    const generatedMelodyButton = document.getElementById('b1b')
    originalMelodyButton.onclick = () => {
      playOriginalMelody()
    }
    generatedMelodyButton.onclick = () => {
      playGeneratedMelody()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
}
```

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: why can't you call it in the `componentDidMount()`? you should add `async` to it in that case.

Comment: added it, and updated question. Buttons still not showing, so i cant test it.

Comment: you're not calling it, you're defining the function inside only. I will show you in an answer.

Comment: thank you so much Pablo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the `startProgram` function from ComponentDidMount (when the compontent is loaded in the application):

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.player.start(this.sequence.BEATB);

    await startProgram();
}
```

However, take into account that the ideal usual to assign behavior to buttons in React should be by declaring them in JSX in the `render()` function and assigning behavior with the `onClick` property.

For example, the first button (which is actually a `div`) can be added its behavior like this (you need to have the `playOriginalMelody` declared at the class level or inside the `render()`):

```
render()
{
  return (
    <div class="b1a" onClick={playOriginalMelody}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you show me? https://codesandbox.io/s/great-buck-2itrb?file=/src/Models/Beats/Beat.js

Comment: @VP9 check here: https://codeshare.io/2KExlz (I couldn't edit yours). You need to test it, though. But the idea is to assign the behavior directly in the div. For the second div that is more complex to refactor (I didn't do it there), given that you depend on `improvisedMelody`. This should be part of the component state for you to be able to use it in the following action.

Comment: The problem with the code as it is now, is that you could click button even before the `startProgram` finishes running. Ideally, the button should be blocked based on the component state until the async action was done.